# Unable to import the database via PLESK

Tags: mysql, database, plesk

I'm trying to import my database via PLESK and still have the same errors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uG4po.png)

- ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 1898: MySQL server has gone away
- Traceback (most recent call last):
- File "/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/dbbackup", line 6, in
- File "/usr/local/psa/lib/modules/python/dbbackup/dbbackup.py", line
  100, in main restore(options, password)
- File "/usr/local/psa/lib/modules/python/dbbackup/dbbackup.py", line
  89, in restore
- raise Exception("program 'mysql' finished with non-zero exit code:
  %d" % p.returncode)
- Exception: program 'mysql' finished with non-zero exit code: 1

I tried to enlarge memory_limit and upload_max_filesize in PLESK PHP Settings but it still doesn't work. I've also checked version of my MySQL (5.5.2) because I found it might be not supported by the latest version of Plesk, but it seems to be OK.

I am beginner in such subjects and I really don't know what to do. Please, rescue me :(

Comment: EDIT: Finally it was about increasing max_allowed_packet variable.

Answer (score 2):

It is timeout issue.
I would suggest increasing wait_timeout in my.cnf

Comment: OK...but.. how?

Comment: Thanks for help. Finally it was max_allowed_packet variable. I had to increase it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hi Todra,**

if you desire to increase the "wait-timeout", you have to define **for example** in your "my.cnf":

**AFTER** => [mysqld]

`interactive_timeout=60
 wait_timeout=60`

In addition, you might consider to set as well:

```
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` -e"SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=60; SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=60"
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot! Finally I had to increase max_allowed_packet variable.